# how to update multiple rows in a single column to use a different time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have a table as follows

```
ID   | DateTime
1    |2021-06-10 14:25:00.000
11   |2021-06-10 14:25:00.000
15   |2021-06-10 14:25:00.000
18   |2021-06-10 14:25:00.000
111  |2021-06-10 14:25:00.000
```

i want to increment the datetime by 1minute for each id

so the outcome should look like

```
  ID      | DateTime
    1    |2021-06-10 14:26:00.000
    11   |2021-06-10 14:27:00.000
    15   |2021-06-10 14:28:00.000
    18   |2021-06-10 14:29:00.000
    111  |2021-06-10 14:30:00.000
```

how can i achieve this in an update statement all at once? since i have like 100 rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an updatable CTE:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT DateTime,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS N
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
UPDATE CTE
SET DateTime = DATEADD(MINUTE, N, DateTime);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c3c6f89d160b9c0e42e6e1f152602c63)